# jQuery not working when sending sync XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code which sends a string into chuncks.
Everything is OK expect that when the script is posting to the server #status doesn't update.
The request is sync and not async because I want to post one chunk at a time and not everything at onces.

```
for (var packet in packets) {
     var calculated = ((packet/(packets_lenght-1))*100);
     $('#status').text(calculated);

     var formData = new FormData();

     formData.append("packet", packets[packet]);
     formData.append("packet_num", packet);
     formData.append("name", 'name');

     var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
     request.open("POST", "index.php", false);
     request.send(formData);

}
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: use $.ajax() ( or $.post() ) in this case

Comment: When using $.ajax with async: false it has the same behavior.

Comment: What type have packet and packets variables?

Comment: I have a string that is splited into chunks. These chunks are packets. And packet is the number of the chunk. I just want the post requests to be one by one and not all at the same time.

Comment: can you put example at jsbin? P.S. You shouldn't use for...in loop with arrays , use for()

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8FQmS/1/ this is it. I have a string. This string is devided into smaller strings. Then every small string must be sent to the server one by one. Also this shoudn't stop executing other js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because browser didn't refresh view state while he is busy by execution code ( js executed in single threat - so in case of sync requests - ints normal )

you should async iterations over array like this http://jsfiddle.net/7TzF8/

Sorry - z made minor changes to just show idea, you can refactor your code according main idea

```
var packets = str2chunk(JSON.stringify(frames_array).split('data:image/jpeg;base64,').join(''), 10);
var packets_lenght = packets.length;

function processPacket(packet){
    if(packet >= packets_lenght){
      return;   
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://fiddle.jshell.net/echo/jsonp/",
        data: {
            packet: packets[packet],
            packet_num: packet,
            name: 'name'
        },
        success: function (answer) {
            console.log(packet);
            var calculated = ((packet / (packets_lenght - 1)) * 100);
            $('#status').text(calculated + '%');
            processPacket(packet+1);
        },
        error: function () {

        }
    });
}

processPacket(0);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Interesting logic.